# Vector spaces of random variables having zero expectation

Tags: stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces

Edit: Robin's comments appear to have made the matter a lot clearer to me. I now suppose that the vector space of random variables with zero expectation are studied in the context of second order stationary processes.

The other question remains: are vector spaces of random variables with non-zero expectation also studied?

Comment: I can't make head nor tail of this. Random variables (sometimes)
have expectations, but vector spaces, to my knowledge, usually
don't.

Comment: The set of random variables forms a vector space. For any two random variables, the inner product is defined as the joint expectation $E\{XY\}$. Furthermore, it is frequently assumed that $E\{X\} = E\{Y\} = 0$. What I would like to know is if this latter assumption is necessary in all cases?

Comment: Right, so you are dealing with a space $L^2(\mu)$ where $\mu$
is a probability measure (why didn't you just say so?).
But I still cannot see what your question is. (You say
"frequently assumed that" - by whom? -  I don't usually
assume that a given random variable has zero expectation.)

Comment: @Olumide: the set of random variables with nonzero expectation does not form a vector space.  However, if X is a random variable, then X - E(X) has zero expectation, so for most purposes it's enough to study X - E(X), which is often technically easier, to study X.

Comment: @Robin I have almost no knowledge of measure theory. I'm a computer scientist/engineering grad student teaching myself mathematics while writing my thesis. As for "frequently assumed", the texts I've come across assume a vector space of zero-mean random variables. However, according to Qiaochu this is a necessary condition.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes": $L^p(\mu)$ the
set of random variables $X$ on the probability space with probability
measure $\mu$ with the property that $E(|X|^p)$ is finite, is
very well-studied, in probability theory and in functional analysis.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu. How about non-stationary processes? Surely $X - E\{X\}$ does not have zero mean. I am a bit surprised that processes with non-zero mean do not form a vector space. I thought all that was required that the set be closed under addition and multiplication. BTW, do we speak of the (universal) set of *all* random variables or just *a* set of random variables? If the former is the case, linear combinations of random variables with different expectations may be inconsistent or invalid. Si?

Comment: @Olumide: Surely, X−E(X) has zero mean, if by “mean” you mean expectation, and if the letter E stands for expectation. If not, you'd better start explaining your terminology and notation. Also, Qiaohcu is absolutely right that the variables with nonzero expectation does not form a vector space, as any vector space contains zero, and also the expecation of E(Y)X−E(X)Y is zero.

Comment: @Harald: by "mean" I mean expectation. Please forgive the following ignorant remarks; are you saying there is a space of processes with non-zero expectation cannot include the zero element? For a while, I struggled don't see why not. However, upon consideration that the expectation of the zero element would have to be zero, (what else could it be?) the condition of a non-zero mean is violated. Also, as you pointed out, the expectation of the linear combination $E(Y)X - E(X)Y$ guarantees the existence of the zero element regardless of the mean of the variables.

Comment: @Olumide: I detect a near total lack of communication here. I think you are misunderstanding something very basic, such as the definition of a vector space, or the basic properties of expectation (which is a linear functional). If I am right about this, then this is not the proper forum in which to try to correct the problem.

Comment: @Harald: I've excused myself three times in previous comments. I am not a mathematician and I'm basically teaching myself. As such many of the things that are obvious to you will require some effort on my part (the reverse might apply if we wandered into my primary field of expertise). What I hoped is that you would better explain why you brought up zero. I'd assumed (perhaps wrongly that) the expectation of a linear combination of random variables is also a random variable even if it is zero valued. Your earlier post stopped short and I'm just trying understand. That's all. Thanks.

Comment: General point: maybe Olumide is looking for an interesting example of a vector space $V$ of random variables where $X \in V$ does not imply ${\rm E}(X)=0$, rather than the impossible case where $X \in V$ implies ${\rm E}(X) \neq 0$ (his question "are vector spaces of random variables with non-zero expectation also studied?" may be interpreted this way).


Comment: @Shai: thanks to zhoraster I now understand why $E(X)$ must be zero. I found Harald's earlier comment very interesting and it seemed to me to contain the a stronger argument -- alas I'm not sure I understand it fully.

Answer (score 3):

One can, of course, think of $L^2(\Omega)$ as of a Hilbert space with a scalar product $E[\xi\eta]$. But for random variables much more important is the covariance $E[\xi\eta]-E[\xi]E[\eta]$. Though it looks at first sight as a scalar product, unfortunately it's not, as $\mathrm{cov}(\xi,\xi)=0$ doed not imply $\xi=0$. However, on the space of centered r.v.'s it is a scalar product. And this Hilbertian structure fully determines the laws in some cases, like a Gaussian case, as Shvai Covo already mentioned. And also this Hilbertian structure plays a very important role for (weakly) stationary processes (also noted by Shvai Covo).

Vector spaces of non-centered random variables are not so popular. One of applications which I think about is financial mathematics, though there you more often work with some cones rather than full vector spaces. Still, a lot of machinery is based (especially in discrete time) on some vector space techniques.

Comment: Thanks! So is it correct to say that the set of random variables with non-zero mean forms a vector space but not a Hilbert space? By the way doesn't $Cov(X,X) = 0$ if $X \ne 0$ imply that the covariance is a seminorm? -- which makes me wonder why seminorms are used/acceptable in the construction of penalties in the development of the theory of splines but not in this case?

Comment: Also, would you please clarify if it is correct to speak of the vector space of all random variables (regardless of the process that generated the observation) or the vector space of random variables generated by a process.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are in the context of second order stationary processes. Then, quoting from Wikipedia (entry on Stationary process), "such a process will be wide sense stationary if the mean and correlation functions are finite". In turn (again, see Wikipedia), the mean function $m_x (t) = {\rm E}\{ x(t)\}$ of a wide-sense stationary process must be constant.
This can account for the assumption of zero expectation you indicated. The situation is similar with regard to Gaussian processes, where it is "frequently assumed" that the process has zero mean; then, as is well known, the law of the process is determined by its covariance.

Comment: I know this. Following Qiaochu's comment, what I would like to know is why random variables with non-zero or even non-constant mean do not form a vector space. In anticipation of an answer to this question I can see why it is important to detrend an observation and make it second-order stationary. This is because the theory of linear predictors on vector spaces is only defined for zero-mean processes.